# MySQL multiple fields referring to one table

Tags: mysql

If I have a table, A, which contains 4 fields, namely

```
productA, typeA, productB, typeB
```

"product*" contains the product name, then "type*" refers to id of table B, which contains

```
id, type
1 , "fooType"
2 , "barType"
```

Now in my table A, I have something like

```
productA, typeA, productB, typeB
"apple" , 1    , "banana", 2
```

Now, I want to retrieve the above row with the correct type information from table B, how the SQL should be? I failed to work with "JOIN ... AND", and "JOIN ... OR" will produce two results.

[edit]

The query I tried,

```
select * from a join b on a.typeA=b.id and a.typeB = b.id
select * from a join b on a.typeA=b.id or a.typeB = b.id
```

Comment: Show the query you do have. You'll need to `FROM A JOIN B b1 JOIN B b2` (that is, join B twice, once for each column in A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be:

```
SELECT
  A.productA,
  B1.type AS typeA,
  A.productB,
  B2.type AS typeB
FROM
  A
    LEFT JOIN B AS B1 ON A.typeA=B1.id
    LEFT JOIN B AS B2 ON A.typeB=B2.id
```